# define stream with complex type attributes

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

```
org.wso2.siddhi.query.api.definition.Attribute
```

can only define elements of type

```
STRING, INT, LONG, FLOAT, DOUBLE, BOOL
```

How to define stream with complex type elements. e.g.

```
Address {
  String street;
  String city;
}
Person{
  String name;
  Address addr;
}
```

How to create a stream of `Person` as defined above.

is it possible to define Stream in term of Pojo class definitions as in ESPER?

Answer (score 0):

In siddhi you cannot define streams in term of Pojo class definitions.
Siddhi only supports tuples and hence you have to define the stream as follows;

E.g.

define PersonStream (name string, address_streat string, address_city string );